# Is it possible to a VM be "shared" by 2 or more virtual networks on Azure?

Tags: azure, networking, vpn

On Azure, I set up the following virtual network:

```
      | gateway    VPN |
Vnet1 |---------  -----| LocalNet1
      |                |

resources

Name | IP address
VM1  | 192.168.0.5
```

I would like to "share" the VM1 to another virtual network. I thought about - and tried - setting another IP on VM1 and creating Vnet2 with a network corresponding to that new IP. But it seems it is not working at all.

These two articles are close, but not exactly what I really need,

- [Virtual Networks in Microsoft Azure (Part 1)](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/cloud-computing/microsoft/virtual-networks-microsoft-azure-part1.html)
- [Connect Multiple On-premises Sites to a Virtual Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690124.aspx)

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: This should be posted on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a VM with multiple NICs in different virtual networks. You can, however, have multiple NICs with each one assigned to different subnets in the same VNet.

Said that, to connect multiple VNets, you need VPN. Once the VPN is connected you will be able to communicate between networks like if they were in the same one.

**Configure a VNet to VNet Connection**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/